# Defining LP investment model in Lindo/Solver

Tags: linear-programming

Models provided below.

My questions are:

1.

`(G+I+M)` after each constraint in the screenshot of the mathematical model below represents *Growth*, *Income* and *Money Market Funds*, but does that mean for example, `G >= 0.20` **multiplied by** `(G+I+M)`?

2.

> Much less stable figures for the forecast net yields are 18%, 12.5%, and 7.5%.

Those three yield values make up the OF, but what's the significance of saying "Much less stable figures..."?

3.

> Suggesting the investment plan with a slightly lower or slightly larger risk level is acceptable.

Am I supposed to create second/third models with lower/higher risk levels than 5.5% for testing? Or am I meant to use the sensitivity reports to figure that out?

**Problem**
Diversification strategy requires any portfolio to be split across three different mutual funds while respecting the following limits:

Between **20% and 30%** to be allocated within *Growth Fund*
Between **20% and 50%** to be allocated within *Income Fund*
No less than **30%** to be allocated within Money *Market Fund*

Current estimates of the risk factors are:
**10%** for the *Growth Fund*
**7%** for the *Income Fund*
**1%** for the *Money Market Fund*

Much less stable figures for the forecast net yields are estimated to be:
**18%** for the *Growth Fund*
**12.5%** for the *Income Fund*
**7.5%** for the *Money Market Fund*

Client is willing to invest up to **£800,000**. Client risk profile indicates an average risk level of **5.5%**. Suggesting the investment plan with a slightly lower or slightly larger risk level is acceptable.

A mathematical model formulated for this problem using **5.5%** as the maximum acceptable average risk level is shown below.

[image]

Lindo gives syntax error when writing `(G+I+M)`.

```
MAX TtlGain) 0.18G + 0.125I + 0.075M
SUBJECT TO
MaxInv)                  G + I + M <= 800000
MinInvGF)                G         >= 0.20(G+I+M)
MaxInvGF)                G         <= 0.30(G+I+M)
MinInvIF)                    I     >= 0.20(G+I+M)
MaxInvIF)                    I     <= 0.50(G+I+M)
MinInvMMF)                       M >= 0.30(G+I+M)
AvRskLvl)    0.10G + 0.07I + 0.01M <= 0.055(G+I+M)
END
```

Final - it seems Lindo/Lingo solution output is better with transformations using `<=` rather than `>=`.  The solution for both is the same but the sensitivity report does not contain negatives when using `<=`. I might post another question asking about that.

```
MAX TtlGain) 0.18G + 0.125I + 0.075M
SUBJECT TO
MaxInv)                   G + I + M <= 800000
MinInvGF)    -0.80G + 0.20I + 0.20M <= 0
MaxInvGF)     0.70G - 0.30I - 0.30M <= 0
MinInvIF)    -0.80I + 0.20G + 0.20M <= 0
MaxInvIF)     0.50I - 0.50G - 0.50M <= 0
MinInvMMF)   -0.70M + 0.30G + 0.30I <= 0
AvRskLvl)  0.045G + 0.015I - 0.045M <= 0
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry got tought stuff irl

text corresponds with screenshot of model

1. i dont understand what you are saying here
   (i  only guess, the whole proper model is already given ?
   (model says it clearly
   (i guess G , I, M are "money"= integer values for €=or *100 for euro cent(s).
   i dont think 2 decimal  value can by modeled with real type, but i can be wrong

look you did

```
MaxInv)                  G + I + M <= 800000 [ you have 800 000 €]
MinInvGF)                G         >= 0.20 [you allow maximum up to 0.20e=20 eurocent be putted Growth Fund]
```

but given model is

```
MinInvGF)                G         >= 0.20(G+I+M)
```

sum( all money)
then multiply by 0.20
="20% of all invested money"

money G >=0.20(all money) (its like "go to store but buy stuff to Kitchen minimum of 20% all money you spend.. you spend 5e, 1or more to K, you spend 100e, 20 or more to K)

btw all should be equals(but didnt checked it

```
MinInvGF)                G         >= 0.20(G+I+M)
MinInvGF)                G         >= 0.20G+0.20I+0.2M
MinInvGF)                0.80G     >= 0.20(I+M)
MinInvGF)                0.80G  -0.20(I+M)         >= 0
MinInvGF)                0.80G  -0.20I-0.20M       >= 0
```

**edit2:**
because of increasing and growing interest of simple math
(LHS)<=(RHS)

#0. rule always apply to both sides the same

#1. rule adding is allowed (variables and values)

#2. rule subtracting is allowed

#3. rule multiplying by 1 positive number (not allowed by 0

#4. rule multiplying by 1 negative number in 2 steps:
Whenever you multiply or divide an inequality by a negative number, you must flip the inequality sign.[1]
then apply normal multiplying

#5. rule dividing = multiplying (/2 is *0.5)

moving LHS to right, then RHS to right and multiply by (-1)

```
//all same constraints
    LHS<=RHS    //-LHS
    LHS-LHS<=RHS-LHS
    0<=RHS-LHS  // -RHS
    -RHS<=-LHS // *(-1)
    RHS>=LHS
```

another examples:

```
(LHS)<= (RHS) //+2.34 -1A -4B 
(LHS)+2.34 -1A -4B <= (RHS)+2.34 -1A -4B

(LHS)<= (RHS) //*123.45  
(LHS)*123.45 <= (RHS)*123.45
```

[1] http://www.platinumgmat.com/gmat_study_guide/inequalities_multiplying

end of edit)

2. i guess these 3 numbers are just given (imagine you put money in bank account and bank says "we forecast +4% profit after year" .. or add interval ( -3% +9% ) - its forecast.
   can be +20% after year as -40%, its only forecast... but its just given numbers to your opt model.
3. in model there is comment not to go above 5.5% ..
   (again, i  only guess, the whole proper model is already given ?
   (i would not change model, only if task/question tell to do so

isnt your part just copy/past model, run opt and tell G,I,M? :-)
or whats the task

Comment: according https://www.lindo.com/doc/online_help/lingo15_0/general_integer_example_compuquick_product_mix.htm syntax in post should work , example: `MinInvGF)  0.80G  -0.20I-0.20M       >= 0`

Comment: @Edison yes ( many solvers has its own specific kind of syntax restrictions, thats the reason I just wrote all forms that comes in my mind with hope some could work  :-) thanks too :-)

Comment: Yeah, `G >= 0.20(G+I+M)` would be `G - 0.2*(G+I+M) <=0` Thanks :) lift-off.

Comment: nice :-) (maybe this was one of purpose of this task, if teacher already knows that model cant be copied & run (error you posted) ... but to understand constraints matrix(s) system a little and do a little adjustments)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120847/discussion-between-user2120-and-edison).

Comment: @Edison added 'edit 2' for increased interest in equations ^^

Comment: I added the final model with transformations of the constraints for other people to see then used this to verify https://www.mathpapa.com/inequality-calculator/. Do you think the Lindo model looks correct?

Comment: @Edison yes model looks good  :-) maybe chat ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513961/is-there-a-preference-for-inequality-operators-in-linear-programming-lindo :)

Comment: (i did answer in chat, its link up in this comment